# Preventing interpolation outside of data extent with LAS Dataset To Raster ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, interpolation, lidar, extents

When I use the `LAS Dataset To Raster tool` in ArcMap I get an unwanted interpolation outside of the actual study area, like this:

[image]

According to Esri this can be prevented by changing the definition of the input LAS dataset: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/las-dataset-to-raster.htm

> Including a study area boundary as a clip constraint in the definition of the input LAS dataset is highly recommended. One reason is to prevent interpolation from occurring outside the real data extent of the survey. Secondly, there can be a severe performance penalty when using natural neighbor options if the data area is not properly defined.

But how do you achieve this? I can't find these options in the `Las Dataset To Raster` menu.

My input values are as follows:

[image]

Defining a processing extent doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping in mind that defining a processing extent did not work, you could run the `Las Dataset To Raster` tool in python and set an analysis mask as follows:

`arcpy.env.mask = "study_area.shp"`

The tool can be used in python with the following function:

`arcpy.LasDatasetToRaster_conversion(in_las_dataset, out_raster, {value_field}, {interpolation_type}, {data_type}, {sampling_type}, {sampling_value}, {z_factor})`

Here is more information about the mask environment setting: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/mask.htm

and the tool (along with python code samples): http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/las-dataset-to-raster.htm

Comment: Yes, I addressed that at the very end of my question. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Linebeck sorry, my bad. Look at the edit I just made

Comment: Thank you. This is what I executed in python, but the result was the same as before: "arcpy.env.mask = "lasdataset"
arcpy.LasDatasetToRaster_conversion(in_las_dataset="lasdataset", out_raster="[the new file and location]", value_field="ELEVATION", interpolation_type="BINNING AVERAGE LINEAR", data_type="FLOAT", sampling_type="CELLSIZE", sampling_value="100", z_factor="1")

Comment: Maybe I should forget using the las dataset to define a border and instead use for example a shapefile. But how do I create a shapefile with the same outline as all of the las files in the las dataset?

Comment: @Linebeck are the las files rectangular?

Comment: Yes, the las files are rectangular. I "solved" my issue creating a polygon outlining the borders of the las files and then creating a new las dataset with the polygon as a surface constraint. Of course, after creating the polygon I could have just used it to clip the raster and didn't really need to bother with the surface constraint.

Comment: @Linebeck an additional benefit to using Surface Constraint in the lasd before creating the raster instead of clipping with it after is that processing time can be orders of magnitude faster. I've seen what used to take ~3.5hrs drop to under 2 minutes.